# Zend sub-folder as DocumentRoot for sub-domain gives invalid controller thinking folder name is a controller

Tags: apache, zend-framework, subdomain

I have a zend project located in the /account sub folder. I want to be able to create sub-domain virtual hosts and point their DocumentRoot to this sub folder

In index.php I have this line that sets the URL of the zend project folder

```
 define('SiteUrlUser','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/account/');
```

The DocumentRoot setup for one sub-domain is

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/account
```

As i'm browsing the site at subomdain.domain.com it always adds /account to the URLs which is normal but then throws this error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (account)'

Now if I remove /account from any URL while accessing the site through a subdomain the pages render just fine. So basically www.domain.com/account/something.html in a subdomain would be subdomain.domain.com/something.html which is working perfectly fine.

I'm planning to setup the server so that all users will login through their sub-domain. The zend folder will be put on it's own server and used as the DocumentRoot for all sub-domains so what would I change in the index.php to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt nest the project inside another non-zend project, i would give it its own root out side the web accessible dir of the other project and point the subdomain there. Then just make your module/controller for account the default via routing.

However if you do nest them then you will have to set the [`baseUrl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.rewritebase)

If the parent project is also a zend app then i would merge the two together and use routing to handle the sub-dir mapping this way you can do a wildcard vhost and point them all to the same application instance on the filesystem.

Comment: There is no parent project. The root folder /var/www is a wordpress installation and /var/www/account is the zend installation (Original members area) Now looking to move this to another server entirely that will handle all the subdomains

Comment: Well then what i mean by "parent project" is the wordpress install. I would be doing as you are suggesting and keeping the zend stuff completely outside the wrodpress structure so for example i might change the wordpress docroot to `/www/somename` and then use `/var/www/accounts/public` as the zend project's web root. So filesystem wise they would be completely isolated.